# Android open Fragment in Pager Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

This `ImagePager Adapter` Class is call from a `Fragment` not on `Activity`. I put the `Activity` to the `getFragmentManager()`;

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater _inflater = null;
    ImageLoader imageLoaderProfile;
    Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Profile> movieItems;
    Button gpsBtn;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, List<Profile> movieItems) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        _inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
        imageLoaderProfile = new ImageLoader(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) _inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_profile, null);

        final Profile m = movieItems.get(position);
        TextView nameView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.profileTitle);
        ImageView cardView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.profileCard);
        nameView.setText(m.getTitle());

        ImageView profileCard = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.profileCard);
        Log.d("Card Name: ", String.valueOf(m.getTitle()));
        imageLoaderProfile.DisplayImage(m.getThumbnailUrl(), profileCard);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Card Name: ", m.getTitle());

                bundle.putString("nombre", m.getTitle());

                InfoProfile frag = new InfoProfile();
                //frag.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.myLayout, frag, "VivzFragment");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                // manager.popBackStack();
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        container.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to open a fragment in a "PageAdpater":

```
FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.myLayout, frag, "VivzFragment");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
// manager.popBackStack();
transaction.commit();
```

Results in this error:

```
at icomm.cardboard.adapters.ImagePagerAdapter$1.onClick(ImagePagerAdapter.java:74)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There should be some more info about the error preceding the stacktrace you posted.  Null pointer exception, bad reference, missing context etc.  There isn't enough here to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Sorry about the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass fragmentManager in the constructor of the pagerAdapter.

```
  FragnmentManager manager;
  public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, List<Profile> movieItems,FragnmentManager manager) {
    super();
    this.manager=manager
    this.context = context;
    _inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
    imageLoaderProfile = new ImageLoader(activity);
}
```

Then call the fragment like this...

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.myLayout, frag, "VivzFragment");
 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
 // manager.popBackStack();
 transaction.commit();
```